# How to catch no such table error sugar?

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am getting this error

 `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:` 

Is there any way to catch it . 
I tried with try and catch and not working app is crashing
My code

```
JsonStroageMilla jsonStroageMilla=new JsonStroageMilla();
jsonStroageMilla.findById(JsonStroageMilla.class,1);
```

My class

```
    @Keep
    public class JsonStroageMilla extends SugarRecord {
        public JsonStroageMilla(){

        }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    String data,time;
  }
```

Full error code

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.valyangadi, PID: 16477
>                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.app/ChecckoutActivity062802}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML
>   file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23:
>   Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                       at com.shopify.sample.checkout.ChecckoutActivity062802.onCreate(ChecckoutActivity062802.java:18)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32:
>   Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                       at com.shopify.sample.checkout.ChecckoutActivity062802.onCreate(ChecckoutActivity062802.java:18) 
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   JSON_STROAGE_MILLA (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM
>   JSON_STROAGE_MILLA
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
>                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1240)
>                                                                       at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:201)
>                                                                       at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:127)
>                                                                     at

Comment: can you share the code please

Comment: And are you sure that the table exists?

Comment: i am using sugar and i don't know how they make table

Comment: we are juest calling object.save() for insert and findbyid for read from sqlite

Comment: I think you are not implementing Sugar correctly, anyway I think the try and catch is working and your app is crashing because of some xml layout problems

Comment: check this  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: JSON_STROAGE_MILLA (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM JSON_STROAGE_MILLA
                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: if it is xml problem then why showing this error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173952/discussion-between-mosius-and-midhilaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try disabling instant
- First uninstall your app from your device/emulator.
- Then clean the project (Android Studio, Build, Clean Project).
- Now run your app.

Comment: Hi, I realized why uninstalling and installing again works ! As the answer below says you should upgrade your data base version every time you add a new table or change the design of a table... So uninstalling is not the real answer and the correct one is version upgrade....... Also note that you have to upgrade by 1 and not 0.1 .

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty constructor and make sure you update your database value with 1, so

```
public JsonStroageMilla() {}
```

and

```
<meta-data
android:name="VERSION"
android:value="2"/>
```

Comment: after updated the code it is still showing the error

Comment: try{
            JsonStroageMilla jsonStroageMilla=new JsonStroageMilla();
            jsonStroageMilla.save();
            Address address=new Address();
            address.save();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("hack","sugar \ne:"+e.getMessage());
        }